# Why pylint returns `unsubscriptable-object` for numpy.ndarray.shape?

Tags: python, numpy, pylint

I just put together the following "minimum" repro case (minimum in quotes because I wanted to ensure `pylint` threw no other errors, warnings, hints, or suggestions - meaning there's a bit of boilerplate):

**pylint_error.py**:

```
"""
Docstring
"""

import numpy as np


def main():
    """
    Main entrypoint
    """
    test = np.array([1])
    print(test.shape[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run `pylint` on this code (`pylint pylint_error.py`) I get the following output:

```
$> pylint pylint_error.py
************* Module pylint_error
pylint_error.py:13:10: E1136: Value 'test.shape' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 1.67/10 (previous run: 1.67/10, +0.00)
```

It claims that `test.shape` is not subscriptable, even though it quite clearly is. When I run the code it works just fine:

```
$> python pylint_error.py
1
```

So what's causing `pylint` to become confused, and how can I fix it?

Some additional notes:

- If I declare test as `np.arange(1)` the error goes away
- If I declare test as `np.zeros(1)`, `np.zeros((1))`, `np.ones(1)`, or `np.ones((1))` the error does ***not*** go away
- If I declare test as `np.full((1), 1)` the error goes away
- Specifying the type (`test: np.ndarray = np.array([1])`) does ***not*** fix the error
- Specifying a `dtype` (`np.array([1], dtype=np.uint8)`) does ***not*** fix the error
- Taking a slice of test (`test[:].shape`) makes the error go away

My first instinct says that the inconsistent behavior with various `NumPY` methods (`arange` vs `zeros` vs `full`, etc) suggests it's just a bug in `NumPY`. However it's possible there's some underlying concept to `NumPY` that I'm misunderstanding. I'd like to be sure I'm not writing code with undefined behavior that's only working on accident.

Comment: I'd blame `pylint` before `numpy`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but it looks like this is an open issue: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3139

Until the issue is resolved on their end, I would just change the line to

```
    print(test.shape[0])  # pylint: disable=E1136  # pylint/issues/3139
```

to my `pylintrc` file.

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue. Unfortunately `pylint` ***also*** complains about lines being too long, so I think I may stick with `print(test[:].shape[0])` over your solution since it makes my lines shorter and saves me from `pylint`s incessant nagging

Comment: NOTE: Recent versions of pylint warn about disabling by ID, so I recommend something more like this on the preceding line:
`# pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object  # pylint/issues/3139`

Answer (score 3):

As of November 2019:

As mentioned by one of the users in the discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3139#issuecomment-535267832) you could resolve the problem by downgrading **both** *pylint* and *astroid*, e.g. in `requirements.txt`

```
astroid>=2.0, <2.3
pylint>=2.3, <2.4
```

or

```
pip install astroid==2.2.5 & pip install pylint==2.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This was finally fixed with the release of astroid 2.4.0 in May 2020.

https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3139